# Showing that the sequence $1,31,331,3331,....$ contains infinitely many composite numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> Let $x_n$ be the sequence
>
> $$1,31,331,3331,....$$
>
> a) Find the nth term of $x_n$
>
> b) Show that the sequence contains infinitely many composite numbers (not primes)

My attempt : for 1st question

$$x_{n}=\frac13\left(10^{n}-7\right)$$
then use induction to prove it

> But what about 2nd question ?

Comment: Suggestion for b):  If $x_n$ is prime for some $n$, prove that is a one-to-one function leading to a larger $n^\prime$ such that $x_{n^\prime}$ that is not prime.

Answer (score 5):

Find a prime $p>3$ where $10^n\equiv 7\pmod{p}$ has a solution.  Then $10^n\equiv 7$ infinitely often.

An obvious candidate to try is $p=17$, since then $10\equiv -7$, so if we can solve $10^n\equiv -1\pmod{17}$ we are done.  Since $17-1=16=2^4$, we can just check this by repeatedly squaring: $10^2\equiv -2$, $(-2)^2\equiv 4$, $4^2\equiv -1$.

Answer (score -1):

Let consider $a_1$ be any number. Create a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3$, where $a_n$ is formed by appending a digit from 0 to 8 to the end of $a_{n-1}$. We may show that this sequence contains infinitely many composite numbers. Assume the sequence contains only prime numbers from some point on. We can even assume it consists of primes only. Then we can never append $0,2,4,6$ or $8,$ (it would be divisible by $2$), nor $5$ (it would be divisible by $5$). This leaves $1,3$ and $7.$ The residue modulo 3 is thus either unchanged or increased by $1.$

As the numbers can not be divisible by $3$ this means that from some point onward we can only append a 3. Again, we can assume we only append 3s. So the numbers have the form
$$
a_n = 10^{n-1} a_1 + \frac{10^{n-1}-1}{3}.
$$
We need to show that $3a_1$ divides $10^{n-1}-1$ infinitely often. But if $a_1$ and $10$ are relative prime, this follows from the Fermat–Euler theorem which implies
$$
10^{\varphi(3a_1)}-1\equiv 0 \pmod {3a_1},
$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. If not, we replace $a_1$ by $a_2=10a_1+3.$

Comment: The OP's question assumes that a digit is prepended, not appended.